# cannot access mysql database through python flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I am attempting to create a flask web application that uses mysql to store users and some other data. When I use the following code

```
import MySQLdb

def connection():
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='password', database='data')
    c = conn.cursor()

    return c, conn
```

I get a 500 internal service error. This code will connect on the command line, and my flask site works fine until I add the line
`from dbconnect import connection`

I have tried using different ways to connect to the database, (python connector, pymysql). They all give the same error. I have also tried updating permissions from inside mysql to the user. I have been following tutorials from https://pythonprogramming.net/flask-connect-mysql-using-mysqldb-tutorial/ but they did not get these errors in the tutorial and I have followed most of the tutorial exactly.

Comment: you should check if the server is running. on port 3306 and also  check the mysql logs if there is a problem.

Comment: Can you add the error you're receiving from the python/terminal output?